# Extract information from multiple log files

Tags: shell-script, files, logs

I am trying to make a `.txt` file that contains only one line gathered from other 30 `.log` files.
To extract only one line I used this:

```
$ sed -n '/Num mapped reads/p' /home/travc/seq_v2/AgamP4_v2/samples/ERS224561/qualimap/qualimap.log > /data/home/odkirling/Mali/Yeah1.txt
```

It works great but now I need to do it for other 29 files, how can I do that?

Comment: What are those other 29 files named? One simplistic solution would be to just repeat that command for the other 29 filenames. Is there a filename pattern that's common to those 30 files and only to those files?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information on the directory structure where the log files are located?

Comment: This is the path for the file home/travc/seq_v2/AgamP4_v2/samples/ERS224561/qualimap/qualimap.log. The only thing that changes is the name of the file "ERS224561"

Comment: Please do not add details in a comment.  Add them in an edit to your question.

Comment: There's a tool that was designed specifically for this kind of job, it's called `grep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```
for filepath in $(ls -1 /home/travc/seq_v2/AgamP4_v2/samples/*/qualimap/qualimap.log);
do
  sed -n '/Num mapped reads/p' $filepath >> /data/home/odkirling/Mali/Yeah1.txt
done
```

This will need the path before and after `*` to be exactly the same.

**Update**

If your files are in a sequence, say `ERS224561` to `ERS224591`, you can use `seq 61 91`. In this case, the script will be

```
for filenum in $(seq -w 30 150);
do
  sed -n '/Num mapped reads/p' "/home/travc/seq_v2/AgamP4_v2/samples/ERS2245$filenum/qualimap/qualimap.log" >> /data/home/odkirling/Mali/Yeah1.txt
done
```

Or let's say you have a list of directories in a text file, in the following format

```
ERS224591
ERS224592
ERS224523
ERS224525
.
.
.
```

then you can do something like

```
for dirname in $(cat dir_names.txt);
do
  sed -n '/Num mapped reads/p' "/home/travc/seq_v2/AgamP4_v2/samples/$dirname/qualimap/qualimap.log" >> /data/home/odkirling/Mali/Yeah1.txt
done
```

`dir_names.txt` is the file containing your directory names. Similarly, you should be able to replace any part of the file path based on your requirements.

Comment: Jyotish, Thanks that works great. The only concern I have is that your code extracts the info from my whole database. What if I want to extract info from 30 out of 150 files?

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I needed and works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

`sed` operates on an input stream that doesn't need to be limited to a single file; use multiple files instead, e.g. by supplying wild card characters in the files' paths like `.../ERS*/.../*log`

Comment: Thanks. So, that means that I have to write the name of each file li this /filename/ filename/ filename/...n/

Comment: Try to analyse, understand and apply my example.

Comment: Thanks, i am trying to understand but i do not...

Comment: @user117970 - well, this is the better answer but any absolute novice would have troubles understanding it...  you need to do some serious reading up on globs/wildcards/filename patterns in order to understand it (at which point you will no longer ask this kind of question).  Also, as I said above, the tool used here (`sed`) isn't the most suited for this task (though it does the job fine, no question).